# LinearLayout horizontal not displayed properly on real device

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am very confuse with LinearLayout in horizontal as it always not display properly  in a narrow width screen device. Here is my code.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/otherLinear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/availableAction"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/add"
                        android:textColor="@color/icon_selected"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/addFriendsBtn"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/welcome"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_icons8_add_user" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:text="@string/report_label"
                        android:textColor="@color/icon_selected"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/reportBtn"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/welcome"
                        android:src="@drawable/icons8_spam" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/followAction"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/follow"
                        android:textColor="@color/icon_selected"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/followBtn"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/welcome"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_follow" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:text="@string/msg"
                        android:textColor="@color/icon_selected"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/msgBtn"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/welcome"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_icons8_weixin_100" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

This is how it looks in AS and this is what I need.
[image]

But this is what I always ended up for unknown reason.
[image]

I also check if its was just because of a long textview but it not. The view is correct in AS but on some real device I already test its not. Can someone enlighten me I am dealing with LinearLayout horizontal for a year making adjustment over and over again.

Comment: What exactly is wrong? the fact that your layout is changing direction/the fact your text collapse?/the fact that on a real phone the layout looks a bit more round than it is on the display?

Comment: It is just because of CardView serves as its parent, I do not want to post the whole xml code it is too long and other stuff there is not related here.

Comment: Ok, so help me out - what exactly is your problem? the text?

Comment: yes the textview

Comment: That's because you are using wrap content on the textView - I can show you how to create an auto size textView, would that be useful?

Comment: What do you mean by auto size textView, is it different from what wrap content do in a layout?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189007/discussion-between-tamir-abutbul-and-mihae).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrap content for your textViews. If your text will be very long so will your view, you can reduce the text size of your textViews in the XML and hope that the text can fit inside 1 line or you can use [autofittextview](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) - "A TextView that automatically resizes text to fit perfectly within its bounds".
Heie is how you use this library :

**In your gradle add this implementation :**

```
 implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.1'
```

**Now add your textView :**

```
   <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:minTextSize="8sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Layout changes depend on device resolution and screen size.
Please visit:

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

or:

You need to add this code in text view:

```
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Comment: I do not want to overuse  ellipsize as much as possible.